# Sending posix signals with "signalProcess" function

Tags: haskell

I can not figure out how to convert integer process id to `CPid` type.
I have a process id as a `String` and signal as `Integer`.
I try to use `signalProcess` function to kill the process.
`signalProcess` takes a `Signal` and `ProcessID` data types.

How do I convert integers to the above data types?

Comment: I do not know System.Posix, but doesn’t `fromIntegral` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPid is an instance of `Integral`, as is `Signal` (which is `CInt`), so `fromIntegral` should do.

Comment: It is more accurate to say that `fromIntegral` should work because `CPid` is an instance of `Num` (rather than `Integral`).